# There are $n$ seats in a room. If $n$ people come to the room, what is the probability that $j$ specified people occupy $j$ specified seats?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**There are $n$ seats in a room. If $n$ people come to the room, what is the probability that $j$ specified people occupy $j$ specified seats? ($j$ names were tagged on the $j$ seats)**

$n$ people can occupy $n$ seats in $n!$ ways.
I can't get my head around how to go forward from here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly $j$ or at least $j$?

Comment: it seems exactly j

Answer (score 3):

$(n-j)!\over {n!}$.  That is because $n-j$ people can sit in $(n-j)!$ ways.  ( $j$ people already sat in $j$ seats. So, rest $(n-j)$ people sit in $(n-j)!$ ways  )